# Block outbound traffic on EC2

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Is ther a way to configure EC2 Security Groups so that they do not allow specific types of outbound connectivity (such as making HTTP requests to the public internet)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, no.  You may have better luck on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), though.

AFAIK, EC2 security groups are only for accessing the server (eg, keypairs); any internal connectivity would probably have to be regulated through `iptables`.

Comment: This isn't the case. SGs can control the ability for external access from the server. See my answer about removing/changing the default allow outbound rule.

Answer (score 0):

Security Groups only let you specify *allow* rules.

To achieve what you're after you would remove the default All traffic/All protocols/All ports/0.0.0.0/0 rule.

This will effectively stop all outbound connections.

If you encounter issues with connectivity after this, add rules to explicitly allow what's needed.